# Escape single quotes in a string

Tags: java, javascript

JSP:

```
<% final String data = "some test with ' single quotes"; %>
<script>
    var str = '<%= data %>';
<script>
```

The result is (JavaScript):

```
var str = 'some test with ' single quotes';
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

How do I replace this single quote with `\'` to avoid a JavaScript error?

Comment: Do you use any web framework?

Comment: what error do you get when you do that?

Comment: You also need to encode the double quotes, new lines, tabs and many other things..

Comment: @JuanMendes no, I don't. I need just escape single quotes. This is inline string without any line breaks

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk Yes you do, how can you possibly control what's in the string? You should be safe and properly escape anything that needs escaping, don't add bad assumptions to the code

Comment: @JuanMendes sorry, you are right, my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`escapeEcmaScript`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29) method from Apache Commons Lang package:

> Escapes any values it finds into their EcmaScript String form. Deals
>   correctly with quotes and control-chars (tab, backslash, cr, ff, etc.).
>   So a tab becomes the characters `'\\'` and `'t'`.
>
> The only difference between Java strings and EcmaScript strings is
>   that in EcmaScript, a single quote and forward-slash (`/`) are escaped.

Example:

> `input string: He didn't say, "Stop!"`
>
> `output string: He didn\'t say, \"Stop!\"`

Comment: Definitely an overkill, because it also converts any non-latin alphabetic symbol into its unicode sequence (`"кириллица"` -> `"\\u043A\\u0438\\u0440\\u0438\\u043B\\u043B\\u0438\\u0446\\u0430"`).

Answer (score 3):

Remember you also need to encode the double quotes, new lines, tabs and many other things. One way to do it is using [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

```
public class JavaScriptEscapeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("input.txt"));
        String results = StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(str);
        System.out.println(results);

    }

}
```

input.txt

> Here is some "Text" that
>   I'd like to be "escaped" for JavaScript.
>   I'll try a couple special characters here: \ "

output

> Here is some \"Text\" that\r\nI\'d like to be \"escaped\" for JavaScript.\r\nI\'ll try a couple special characters here: \ \"

Comment: There is no `escapeJavaScript` method anymore.

Comment: @VisoN renamed in 3.1, was there until 2.6

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? It's correct if you're using  org.apache.commons 2.6 (the version we were stuck at work with). Also, this question was closed linking to an answer that says the exact same thing I said...

Comment: I don't know who dvoted you, but I personally think that your answer should be considered at least for backwards compatibility. I doesn't worth negative grade.

Comment: @VisioN Thanks for the compensatory upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to simply double-escape your string so you actually have a `\` followed by a `'`?

```
<% final String data = "some name with \\' single quote"; %>
```

From your JavaScript code, you can use the [string replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) functionality:

```
var str2 = str1.replace("'","\\'");
```

Comment: Data is not hardcoded. I fetch it from databese and have to replace single quotes

Comment: I don't think it's a hardcoded string the OP is worried about